# Can't write array to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim HighScoreOneHourData() As Integer
Dim HighScoreOneHourDates() As String

ReDim HighScoreOneHourData(1 To UBound(SA, 1) - 3)
ReDim HighScoreOneHourDates(1 To UBound(SA, 1) - 3)

For j = 4 To UBound(SA, 1)
    HighScoreOneHourData(j - 3) = CInt(Val(SA(j, PositionInArray + DataColumn + 2)))
    HighScoreOneHourDates(j - 3) = SA(j, 1)
Next j

SortSheet.Range("A1:A" & UBound(HighScoreOneHourDates)) = HighScoreOneHourDates
SortSheet.Range("B1:B" & UBound(HighScoreOneHourData)) = HighScoreOneHourData
```

When these last two lines in the example above are executed all the cells in the sheets are filled with the first element from the arrays.

HighScoreOneHourDates is an array filled with consecutive dates. Still only the first date is printed to the sheet.

I've stopped the code and checked the state of the arrays and the they are correctly filled.

Anyone knows why the cells are filled with the first element?

Comment: You need to size your arrays using redim because you have declared your arrays as dynamic ( '()').  Given that this is another post from you on a similar topic, you might be best served by doing some reading up on VBA arrays.  SO is supposed to be a 'last resort' resource not an 'opps I've tripped over a matchstick' resource.

Comment: Oh sorry, I posted the wrong code. The first two lines should be ```ReDim HighScoreOneHourData(1 To UBound(SA, 1) - 3)
ReDim HighScoreOneHourDates(1 To UBound(SA, 1) - 3)```

Comment: Btw, I always google extensively before I post on here. Couldn't find an answer to my question so this was my last resort. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1D array always wants to be placed on a sheet in a *row*, not a column. That's why you only get the first element repeated. You need to re-orient the array to put it in a column, or make your arrays 2D (1 To numHere, 1 To 1)

Note there is a limit to the array size you can pass to `Transpose` of around 63-64k elements.

Assuming your arrays are 1-based you can do this:

```
SortSheet.Range("A1:A" & UBound(HighScoreOneHourDates)) = _
                     Application.Transpose(HighScoreOneHourDates)
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you! Transpose did the trick. I need about 5000 elements so well within the limits.

Answer (score 2):

It's been explained *why* 1D arrays don't work for you.  A better fix is to Dim them as 2D

```vb
ReDim HighScoreOneHourData(1 To UBound(SA, 1), 1 To 1) As Integer
ReDim HighScoreOneHourDates(1 To UBound(SA, 1), 1 To 1) As String

For j = 4 To UBound(SA, 1)
    HighScoreOneHourData(j - 3, 1) = CInt(Val(SA(j, PositionInArray + DataColumn + 2)))
    HighScoreOneHourDates(j - 3, i) = SA(j, 1)
Next j

SortSheet.Range("A1:A" & UBound(HighScoreOneHourDates, 1)) = HighScoreOneHourDates
SortSheet.Range("B1:B" & UBound(HighScoreOneHourData, 1)) = HighScoreOneHourData
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked too! Maybe it's better than transpose? Fewer steps?